# why /public folder for static content in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

In node.js with express all the static content is placed in /public folder. Can someone help me understand why do we need to place it particularly in public folder? What if I want to create a folder called 'static' with in 'views' folder and keep all images, styles and script files in it. Because I want keep all thing related to views under one folder. If it is not good way of structuring project please help me in understanding reasons behind it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put your content in any folder you want on the server.  All that matters is how you set up your Express routes to serve that public content.  You can name the local server folder `/public` or `/static` or whatever you want and you can put it anywhere in your folder hierarchy that you want too (like in some project directory).  You will just need to set the path in your `express.static()` middleware to match where you put the content on your server so express knows where to look for it to match a given incoming request.

Comment: BTW, one should not serve static files from node/express server but use a CDN or at least use a webserver like apache or nginx to serve those files.

Comment: @MarufManiruzzaman - That's kind of a ridiculous generalization.  Maybe if you're deploying a large scale multi-server deployment, you would think about paying for a CDN or deploying other infrastructure to server static files, but LOTS of servers just don't need that added expense or complexity and a single node.js server or a simple node.js cluster on one server is more than adequate.  So, your comment makes some sense at a larger scale, but not generically.  And, as with most things, that extra complexity or expense should not be added until there is a proven need for it.